# Sort Django objects by method with arguments

Tags: python, django

I have a model called Task that returns a date depending on the user. It defines a method:

```
def date_for_display(self, user):
  # return some date for the task
```

I want to create a list of tasks sorted by the date returned by this method. I tried something like:

```
user = User.objects.get(username="jamie")
sorted(Task.objects.all(), key = lambda task: task.date_for_display(user))
```

But to no avail. I get `NameError: global name 'user' is not defined`. Do I need to use a closure of some sort to accomplish this? Not sure how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to use a keyword parameter in your lambda:

```
user = User.objects.get(username="jamie")
sorted(Task.objects.all(), key = lambda task, user=user: task.date_for_display(user))
```

This copies the user from the outer scope into the local scope of your lambda.